# UITableView Detecting Last Cell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, scroll, detect

How can I detect when a `UITableView` has been scrolled to the bottom so that the last cell is visible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Implement the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method in your UITableViewDelegate and check to see if it's the last row.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  I'm actually using this method to trigger an event and it looks like because it's "Will" display, it happens before it actually displays the cell.  Is there a method that fires after the cell is displayed?

Comment: Alas, no. You could fudge a little by using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` with a very short delay to call a method that does what you need.

Comment: @ArtGillespie Found exactly what I was looking for. Cheers !

Comment: willDisplay for last cell is called in my app at the beginning of tableview load data

Answer (score 41):

Inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ...

    NSInteger sectionsAmount = [tableView numberOfSections];
    NSInteger rowsAmount = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
    if ([indexPath section] == sectionsAmount - 1 && [indexPath row] == rowsAmount - 1) {
        // This is the last cell in the table
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: you might as well have said I'm a dummy. thanks for the help sometimes I think these things are harder than they are.

Comment: numberOfSections calls datasource numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection calls datasource numberOfRowsInSection. And in my implementation it got crashed showing this recursive log of this execution.

Answer (score 14):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [tableView numberOfSections] - 1;
    NSInteger lastRowIndex = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;
    if ((indexPath.section == lastSectionIndex) && (indexPath.row == lastRowIndex)) {
        // This is the last cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Create elegant extension for `UITableView`:

```
extension UITableView {

    func isLast(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

        let indexOfLastSection = numberOfSections > 0 ? numberOfSections - 1 : 0
        let indexOfLastRowInLastSection = numberOfRows(inSection: indexOfLastSection) - 1

        return indexPath.section == indexOfLastSection && indexPath.row == indexOfLastRowInLastSection
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView.isLast(for: indexPath) {
        //do anything then
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5+

```
//Show Last Cell (for Table View)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    if indexPath.row == (yourdataArray.count - 1) 
    {
        print("came to last row")
    }
}

//Show last cell (for Collection View)
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    if indexPath.row == (yourdataArray.count - 1)
    {
        // Last cell is visible
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you do it if instead of indexPath.row using indexPath.section? My app has a lot of sections and I would like it to detect when the user scroll to the last section.

Comment: every cell has there own last cell

Comment: Can it works on the multiple sections but each sections only have 1-2 row?

Comment: yes its is very easy just use this code in your mention section and done

Answer (score 3):

For Xcode 8 and swift 3

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let lastSectionIndex = tableView.numberOfSections - 1
        let lastRowIndex = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSectionIndex) - 1
        if indexPath.section ==  lastSectionIndex && indexPath.row == lastRowIndex {
            print("this is the last cell")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      let contentOffsetMaxY: Float = Float(scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.size.height)
      let contentHeight: Float = Float(scrollView.contentSize.height)
      let lastCellIsVisible = contentOffsetMaxY > contentHeight + somePaddingIfWanted
      if lastCellIsVisible {
           doSomething()
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with the willDisplayCell method. This works for me:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let y = scrollView.contentOffset.y/(scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)
    let relativeHeight = 1 - (table.rowHeight / (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height))
    if y >= relativeHeight{
        print("last cell is visible")
    }
}
```

Just pass this in the delegate methods, and change 'table' to your tableView.